# Quand utiliser à ou de

Tags: prononciation

Salut, aidez moi à faire la difference entre de ou à au debut de ces 4 phrases:

L’Ecole Adventiste Maranatha s’engage:

- à/de se conformer strictement à la règlementation officielle sur les établissements d’enseignement privé
- à/de appliquer les programmes et horaires prévus officiellement.
- à/de se soumettre aux agents des corps de contrôle en mission dans l’établissement, notamment ceux relevant du Ministère Pré universitaire et de l’alphabétisation.
- à/de demander à ses enseignants d’avoir l’autorisation d’enseigner.

Comment: On s'engage toujours **à** faire quelque chose, jamais **de** faire quelque chose.

Comment: Et bien, 'ça fait devoirs. Il faut le faire soi-même. Sinon on n'apprend rien....

Answer (score 1):

Jusqu'au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle, l'usage n'était pas figé et *à* comme *de* se rencontraient après *engager*.

Vaugelas à écrit en 1687 (Remarques sur la langue française) :

> Le verbe *engager* me paraît demander *à*. *Je l'ai engagé à me servir, je m'engage à faire cela pour vous*. Beaucoup pourtant disent et écrivent, *engager de faire, s'engager de faire*. Je ne voudrais mettre *de* qu'afin d'éviter la cacophonie du parfait indéfini. *Il s'engagea d'aller*, pour ne pas dire, *Il s'engagea à aller*.

Ses recommandations ont été suivies, et *à* s'est imposé, même devant *aller*.